# Hiding the top panel in Centos 7

Tags: centos, gnome

So I am currently using these commands to hide the top panel in Centos 7:

```
/usr/bin/gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'box=Main.panel.actor.get_parent();'

/usr/bin/gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'box.visible=false;'
```

Which works great, but I'm not able to make these commands run at the start of the user session. I tried to create an `sh` script and make a `.desktop` file in the `~/.config/autostart` , but no luck, any suggestions?

Also, I tried putting the commands in the `.bashrc` and the `.bash_profile` files, also with no luck. I'm missing something...

Comment: Why not using a [shell extension ?](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The gnome shell version that I have is the 3.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I found the answer myself.

I call a Terminal and Run the command. And then, the autostart worked.

```
gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'box=Main.panel.actor.get_parent();'"
sleep 3
gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'box.visible=false;'"
```

It was odd, but it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few years old but just happened to find this as it may help and you only need one line of code plus it not only hides the panel but reclaims the space where it resided...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264686/is-there-a-way-to-hide-ubuntu-dock-and-top-bar-using-terminal

> GNOME way to hide:
>
> ```
> gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.actor.hide();'
> ```
>
> GNOME way to show:
>
> ```
> gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.actor.show();'
> ```
>
> And as an added bonus the Ubuntu way to hide:
>
> ```
> gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Extensions --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.DisableExtension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
> ```
>
> Ubuntu way to show:
>
> ```
> gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Extensions --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.EnableExtension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
> ```

I take no credit in this as it was someone else that answered it, I just really hope that it helps someone that is looking for another way like I was.  The OP posted their answer but that way still shows a blank area at the top when running windows maximized and this way reclaims all the space so that even a window that is maximized uses all of the space.